# Delete duplicate rows having count greater than 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql

Need some help on a MySQL query to delete the rows where the userID count is greater than one and has an acl value=4.

What I've tried as the select query:

```
DELETE FROM `users_acl` 
WHERE userID IN(
    SELECT * FROM `users_acl` 
    WHERE `acl` BETWEEN 2 AND 4 
    GROUP BY userID 
    HAVING COUNT(userID) > 1
);
```

But can't find a proper way to delete the rows in the same query.

Table structure

```
+--------+-----+---------+
| userID | acl | deleted |
+--------+-----+---------+
|     27 |   2 |       0 |
|     28 |   2 |       0 |
|     31 |   2 |       0 |
|     42 |   2 |       0 |
|     42 |   4 |       0 |
|     45 |   1 |       0 |
|     51 |   1 |       0 |
|     54 |   1 |       0 |
|     63 |   2 |       0 |
|     63 |   4 |       0 |
|     64 |   1 |       0 |
|     69 |   2 |       0 |
|     73 |   2 |       0 |
|     73 |   4 |       0 |
|     76 |   1 |       0 |
|     77 |   2 |       0 |
|     77 |   4 |       0 |
+--------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: What will be your expected result set for above data set ?

Comment: The expected result would be to have the user row deleted where the acl = 4 and the user has both acl 2 and 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MySQL you can't select from a table you are deleting from at the same time. But with a temp table you can overcome this problem

```
DELETE FROM `users_acl` 
WHERE userID IN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
       SELECT userID
       FROM `users_acl`
       GROUP BY userID 
       HAVING COUNT(userID) > 1
       AND SUM(`acl` = 4) > 0
   ) tmp
);
```

or use a `join`instead

```
DELETE u
FROM `users_acl` u
JOIN 
(
    SELECT userID
    FROM `users_acl`
    GROUP BY userID 
    HAVING COUNT(userID) > 1
    AND SUM(`acl` = 4) > 0
) tmp on tmp.userID = u.userID
```

Comment: Thanks @juergen d, your solution matched the desired result on the your first example. Seems like I was missing the second inner query.

Comment: Yes, in MySQL you can't select from a table you are deleting from at the same time. But with a temp table you can overcome this problem

Comment: Yes, missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the accepted answer here would actually delete all the duplicates, rather than preserving one unique value.

In case anyone is like me and looking to de-duplicate (rather than delete all duplicates), here's a slightly modified solution:

```
DELETE u
FROM `users_acl` u
JOIN 
(
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(userID) as min_id, MAX(acl) as value
FROM `users_acl` 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY name,value,timestamp,ip HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) tmp on u.id > tmp.min_id and u.value = tmp.value
```